# Is there a distinction between pointers and references?

Tags: terminology, programming-languages

If so, what are the similarities and differences between the two? I’ve only worked with [properties](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html) while programming.

Comment: [This has already been asked on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in)

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: This is a topic that has probably been coverend thousands of times by different sources. What have you read? What is your understanding? What _don't_ you understand in which source? (_That's_ where an interesting question may lie.)

Comment: @Gokul, do you imply that the behavior of pointers and references in Swift is the same as in C++? I have not learned Swift yet.

Comment: @Austin, it is probably far better for you to ask and search programming questions on StackOverflow instead, even though your question might be on-topic here. By the way, if you are learning Swift, I assume, always add "Swift" as a keyword in your search and question. All programming languages are not the same. That being said, I am voting to close this question.

Comment: @Apass.Jack My reference was to the more general query - I didn't notice OP wanted it to be relevant to Swift.

Comment: This general question will be rejected by Stack Overflow as not specific enough (they will say: show us your code, then ask a question about it).

Comment: @Gokul As far as I can see, the question that you referenced is specifically about C++. All links pertain to C++.